# Jenkins clones wrong branch/version from GIT/Gerrit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit-trigger

I am using Gerrit review combined with Jenkins.

As a developer pushes his/hers code to GIT they push using:

git push HEAD:refs/for/master

In jenkins I use the gerrit trigger to trigger build when "patchset created"

The settings in Jenkins look like:

> GIT:
>
> ssh://git.server.com/path/to/project
>
> Refspec: $GERRIT_REFSPEC
>
> Branches to build: left empty or $GERRIT_BRANCH or refs/changes/*
>
> GERRIT TRIGGER:
>
> Trigger on: "Patchset Created"
>
> PROJECT:
>
> Path: path/to/project
>
> branch:**

The build is triggered okay as the push is made but it clones out the wrong version/branch. The changes pushed are not in the code built. Am I thinking wrong here?

As you can see I tried different branches in the GIT plugin. But jenkins git plugin clones out the wrong version/branch.
What am I doing wrong?

I have other jobs triggering on "ref updated" that work fine.

Comment: **Branches to build** should be set to `$GERRIT_BRANCH`. What is the value of `$GERRIT_BRANCH` in the build that you believe is on the wrong branch?

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution (correct if I'm wrong :))

In the 'Branches to build" section of the GIT plugin put in the GERRIT environment variable:

$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION